# How to point to and extract data from Sharepoint excel file

Tags: python, excel, numpy, sharepoint, office365

I have an excel file stored in Sharepoint. How would I use python to point to this file, so that I can manipulate and work on the excel file that is within it.

This is what I am doing

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

url = 'https://yoursharepointsite.com/sites/documentsite'
username = 'yourusername'
password = 'yourpassword'
relative_url = '/sites/documentsite/Documents/filename.xlsx'


import openpyxl
import xlwings as xw


#workbook using xlwings
wls = xw.Book('wls_.xlsm')
```

However, when I type in:

```
relative_url
```

to the jupyter notebook, the output that I am getting is:

```
'/sites/documentsite/Documents/filename.xlsx'
```

**Desired**

Actual output data of the excel file

However, the output is not showing me the data that is ***within*** this file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well, yeah, you didn't import the data yet, when you type into the notebook the variable you have defined it returns the variable. Which in this case is a string location to the file you want to read.

You're going to need to pd.read_excel() that file to have it import the data.

Here's a link to get you started: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Ok @Christopher, I am using xlwings. So can I do something like:  wls = xw.Book(''relative_url')  Thank you I will try